# Reversing list of tuples in an if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 strings as follows:

```
string = '''māori,english
Aotearoa,New Zealand
Te Ika-a-Māui,North Island
Te Waipounamu,South Island'''
```

And:

```
string = """english,māori
New Zealand,Aotearoa
North Island,Te Ika-a-Māui
South Island,Te Waipounamu"""
```

The first line is a header that states what order the translation is in, i.e english,māori or māori,english. Then following are anywhere from 1 to n lines, each with two words separated by a comma.

I have to print it as a list of tuples. The first element of the tuple is the English term, and the second is the Māori term.

My current code is:

```
def get_translations(string):
    """stuff"""
    list1 = []
    lines = string.splitlines()
    for seperate_words in lines:
        list1.append(tuple(seperate_words.split(",")))
    return list1[1:]
```

This works for the second string but not the first as it does not reverse the tuples. Using an if statement how would I reverse the words to be in English then Maori.

I have tried doing this but am unable to do so using list1[::-1] as this prints it backwards

Additionally if the header contains a language other than english and maori then i need to print

```
"Header language not recognized!"
```

The test is

```
for terms in get_translations(string):
print(terms)
```

Any help on how to reverse the list would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work if I understood what you wanted to do:

```
def get_translations(string):
    """stuff"""
    list1 = []
    lines = string.splitlines()
    order = 1 if string.split(',')[0] == "english" else -1
    for seperate_words in lines:
        list1.append(tuple(seperate_words.split(",")[::order]))
    return list1[1:]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thankyou. I'm now wondering how I can get this code to only return list1 if the header contains English and Maori and not another language. Such as if the header contained the language Italian, how could I get my program to print "Header language not recognized!". I have tried using an if statement but have had no luck.

Comment: I have tried this:     if string.split(',')[0] != "māori" or "english":
                              print("Header language not recognized!")

Comment: Try printing evaluation of your expression to see why it fails `print(string.split(',')[0] != "māori" or "english")`. Please mark the question as resolved if my answer helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I can't make sense of it. I need to print "Header language not recognized!" if either of the languages is not Maori or English but currently I can only get it to print it if the first language is not recognized. If the second language is not recognized it still returns list1 as it only goes off the first language.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/#using-or-with-common-objects). Given your current syntax, if the first language is "english", `string.split(',')[0] != "māori"` evaluates to `True` and `True or "english"` evaluates to `True`. However, if the first language is "maori", `string.split(',')[0] != "māori"` evaluates to `False` and `False or "english"` evaluates to "english".

Comment: I managed to do it by using: if 'english,māori' in string. As well as: if 'māori,english' in string. then using an else statement to print the phrase "Header language not recognized!" if neither of those if statements were True. Thanks for the help